# CSS Gradient Text with transparent background

Tags: html, css

**Reference Image**

[image]

**HTML Mock-Up**

```
<div class="Title">
    Raffle <span>BANANZA</span>
</div>
```

**Notes**

This does not *have* to have a gradient however it would be much preferred.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Comment: I'm looking for something more cross-browser @rwacarter

Comment: "Bananza" should, unless this is a deliberate misspelling, be "[bonanza](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bonanza+definition)."

Comment: @TimMarshall which browsers in particular? `background-clip` is IE>8, and you can use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create the cross-browser gradients (with a solid colour fallback)

Comment: Completely different @DavidThomas My organisation is called "Raffle Bananza" - [What does 'Bananza' mean?](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bananza)

Comment: Here is [the CSS Text Gradient example link that was an answer but is better as a comment](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define `svg`'s `linearGradient`s and apply them to the `text`s' `fill`.

[image]

```html
<svg width="275" height="37">
  <style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light);
    text {
      font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-anchor: middle;
      fill: url(#g1);
    }
    text:first-of-type {
      font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
      font-weight: thin;
      font-size: 35px;
      fill: url(#g2);
      white-space: pre;
    }
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="g1" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FDCD2D" />
    <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#DD881A" />
    <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FCEC76" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD881A" />
    <stop offset="73%" stop-color="#FCEC76" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDCD2D" />
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="g2" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#D2DAE3" />
    <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#D2DAE3" />
    <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#839198" />
    <stop offset="73%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
  </linearGradient>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <text x="50" y="34">Raffle </text><text x="180" y="34">BANANZA</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Text is wrong and I don't have source file :( But as for the gradient - amazing!

Comment: @TimMarshall - Hmmm What do you mean text is wrong?

Comment: How would I wrap a link around both? I just tried but it did not work. Never used <svg></svg> before!

Comment: Oh I meant the font-family on the "Raffle" part but I'm sure I'll find something similar :)

Comment: @TimMarshall - I've updated the code and yes you could simply change the `@import url()`, if you wish to change the `font-family`.

Comment: Just tried removing such as space between using `margin:0; padding:0;`could you let me know how to change the gap space and I think that's it :)

Comment: @TimMarshall - You'll have to play around with the `x` value of the `text` element.  `svg` doesn't have `margin` or `padding` attributes. Also, if the text overflows, simply increase the `width` in `svg` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a [1x100px gradient image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7pP6.jpg) and overlay it over the text. It's not purely-css, but by disabling pointer events on the overlay, the text is still selectable.

[image: Screenshot]

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    Raffle <span>BANANZA!</span>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div
{
    font-family: Rockwell;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;

    position: relative;

    color: #999;
}

div span
{
    color: #ea0;
}

div div.overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    z-index: 1;

    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7pP6.jpg.png") repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 0.8;

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5o0o0ac9/3/)

Comment: I do like this but can't notice it much

Comment: @TimMarshall I have the opacity of the overlay down considerably. I didn't want to completely overpower it, and the example image I used is a very simple bilinear gradient.

Comment: Wow there are two Tim Marshall's here. Confusing haha O.o

Comment: Haha, I didn't notice that! This version looks much better. I think we have an answer here :D

Comment: @DavidThomas does this only work on white background?

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure css solution with [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
:root{background: #ccc}
span{
    font-family: Rockwell;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(12%,rgba(240,183,161,1)), color-stop(18%,rgba(140,51,16,1)), color-stop(18%,rgba(140,51,16,1)), color-stop(31%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(53%,rgba(140,51,16,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(191,110,78,1)));
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.8;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span> RaffleBANANZA!</span>
```